# Finding the largest number on a list.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Please help!
I am writing a python program which would find the largest number on a list.
But I am getting a TypeError.

```
numbers = int(input('Size of elements : '))
arr = list()

for h in range(numbers):
    ele = int(input("Enter your input:\n"))
    arr.append(ele)

print(arr)

maximum = numbers[0]
for number in numbers:
    if number > maximum:
        maximum = number


print(maximum)
```

I am getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C://Finding the largest number on a list.py", line 10, in 
maximum = numbers[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `for number in arr`

Comment: and `arr[0]`, not `numbers`

Comment: why not just `maximum = max(numbers)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numbers` is indeed an integer. You've mixed your variables `arr` and `number`

```
maximum = arr[0]
for number in arr:
    if number > maximum:
        maximum = number
```

Answer (score 0):

simply and easily use ***max(list)*** built-in function as follow

```
l = [1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5]

print(max(l))
```

output

```
9
```

Comment: I am practicing "For loops" and hence I am sticking to that. I know I can use max() method too. Anyways, thanks for helping.